# Google Drive - Shared Drives - Script to automatically copy when any new files are added to a shared drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm looking to make use of a script that will make a copy of any new files that are added to Google Drive -> Shared Drive -> (Drive name)

Ideally, I would like this copy to be moved to another Shared Drive and not have the title `"Copy of "` inserted before the name ... but I'm not sure if it can be. *(Side note: I can't get this to work... maybe it's because the other shared drive is owned by another?)*

One of my problems is that I don't understand how to limit the copy function to only files that are newly added vs. added after a certain date.

All of my tests have led to a complete copy of the folder. I can't seem to limit it to new files.  Also, I can't seem to avoid the addition of "Copy of " added to the start of each new file name.

What I have been able to get to work: I can (yes) copy the entire contents (all dates) of any given folder to a folder that I created in the root (not shared) google drive (I named it backup)..

```
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) { 
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId); 
    file.getParents().next().removeFile(file); 
    DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId).addFile(file); 
}
```

Comment: No need to apologize for being new to programming. Your Q is well placed. Personally, I find Google's documentation for app-scripts cumbersome and confusing...

Answer (score 1):

To check the created files after the last time you ran the script you can use the property service [1] to save the date milliseconds and compare it with the file created date, which you can get using `getCreated()` function to each file [2]. To copy the file with a custom name use `makeCopy` function [3]. To completely remove the file (not trash bin) use the delete request [4] with Drive Advance Service (you have to activate it) [5].

```
function moveFiles(sourceDriveId, targetFolderId) { 
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var lastUpdate = scriptProperties.getProperty('lastUpdate');
  if(lastUpdate == null) {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('lastUpdate', new Date().getTime());
    return;
  }

  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  var sourceDrive = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceDriveId);
  var files = sourceDrive.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    if(file.getDateCreated().getTime() > lastUpdate) {
      file.makeCopy(file.getName(), targetFolder); 
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId(), {supportsAllDrives: true});
    }
  }  
  scriptProperties.setProperty('lastUpdate', new Date().getTime());  
}

function test() {
  moveFiles("[SOURCE-DRIVE-ID]", "[TARGET-FOLDER-ID]");
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdatecreated

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination

[4] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete

[5] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive